# choosing specific column value from the input xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i have the below xml as input for which i have to do the xsl transformation

```
<emml>
    <tradeEventHeader>
        <tradeIdentifier>
            <tradeId>104823343913</tradeId>
            <systemReference>RDS</systemReference>
            <systemDomainName>Internal</systemDomainName>
        </tradeIdentifier>
        <tradeStateIdentifier>
            <tradeStateId>Validated</tradeStateId>
            <systemReference>RDS</systemReference>
            <tradeStateIdClassificationScheme>Vn State</tradeStateIdClassificationScheme>
        </tradeStateIdentifier>
        <tradeStateIdentifier>
            <tradeStateId>Pending</tradeStateId>
            <systemReference>Swapswire</systemReference>
            <tradeStateIdClassificationScheme>Mang State</tradeStateIdClassificationScheme>
        </tradeStateIdentifier>
        <tradeStateIdentifier>
            <tradeStateId>accpt_novated_sw</tradeStateId>
            <systemReference>RDS</systemReference>
            <tradeStateIdClassificationScheme>Clearing State</tradeStateIdClassificationScheme>
        </tradeStateIdentifier>
    </tradeEventHeader>
    <emmlExtension systemId="RDS YTO">
        <emmlMediumString idref="legId1" name="Roll Date Option">Short Initial</emmlMediumString>
    </emmlExtension>
</emml>
```

as shown above in the input xml basically my objective is to identify the value of tradeStateIdClassificationScheme parameter and if the value of this parameter is equal to 'Clearing state' then with correspond to that i have to check the value of another column tradeStateId and if the value of the column tradeStateId starts with accpt_novated_sw then in that case we need to return true string and for rest other i need to return false string ..

i have come up with the below template in xslt 1.0 , please advise is it correct approach..

calling template :-

```
<isClearedNovated>
            <xsl:call-template name="cleared_novated">
            <xsl:with-param name="tradeStateId" select="emml/*/*/tradeStateIdentifier" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            </isClearedNovated>


called template :-      



<xsl:template name="cleared_novated">
        <xsl:param name="tradeStateId" />

        <xsl:for-each select="$tradeStateId/tradeStateIdClassificationScheme">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$tradeStateId[starts-with(tradeStateIdClassificationScheme,'accpt')] and systemReference='RDS'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand, what exactly your needs are, but your XSLT probably does not what you want - I suspect it does nothing...

So maybe we can start with the suggestion below and you can tell, what has to be refined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//tradeStateIdClassificationScheme"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tradeStateIdClassificationScheme[
                            . = 'Clearing State' and 
                            ../tradeStateId = 'accpt_novated_sw' and
                            ../systemReference = 'RDS'
                            ]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,': true&#x0a;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tradeStateIdClassificationScheme">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,': false&#x0a;')"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@*|*"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

You find two templates dealing with `tradeStateIdClassificationScheme`, one matches your conditions, and one for all others.

Note that you didn't write about the contents of `systemReference`, while your trial template addresses this element. Therefore, I added this condition as well.

The output in this version is:

```
Vn State: false
Mang State: false
Clearing State: true
```

Comment: Thanks can you also please advise will it work in xslt 1.0 also .

Comment: thanks a lot can you also please advise let's say I want only clearing state true to get printed only then how can I achieve this

Comment: Shall I comment out the second template as o want where the attribute tradeStateIdClassificationScheme is equal to clearing for that only true to be printed and for rest others it should not print anything please advise how to achieve this